# AndroidStudio can't recognize labHelper class for some reason?

Tags: java, android

I am working on implementing in app purchases into my android app. I came across this issue, while writing my code.

My Android Studio can't seem to recognize my labHelper class for some reason, and no this is not a simple cache/restart android studio problem.

Here is the error:
[image: Error]

Now, seems obvious I forgot the labAsyncInProgressException, right?
[image: Error2]

It does not recognize such a class exists.

But sure enough[image: error3] it does exist in the source code:

And the name spacing or name of the class is correct so the error is not there if you were wondering.

Has anyone ran into a problem like this? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Be careful of lower case ell vs upper case eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Class name started with lower case is such a bad habit.
2. void PurchaseItem(String something) *throws* **Something**

**Something** need to be a Class name, not a method name. And you have no such a class as "labAsyncInProgressException" inside util folder.